# Google Spreadsheet freezes when done running App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an app script attached to my Google Spreadsheet. There is a function that does a bunch of stuff withing the spreadsheet. Here is what it does.

1. Create a new Sheet
2. Set column header for new sheet
3. Copy data in new sheet
4. Set Formulas
5. Delete Extra columns
6. Delete Extra rows
7. Add A row in an existing sheet(Sheet 1)
8. Add a column in an existing sheet(Sheet 2)
9. Add Formula in new column in Sheet 2
10. Edit Value in an existing sheet's cell (Sheet 3).

After these 10 steps are complete, the spreadsheet works normally but after 10-15 secs, the sheet will freeze. To get it to work, I need to refresh the page.

I experimented and I found out that if I eliminate Step 6 i.e "Delete Extra rows", the freeze behavior is eliminated. Why does it freeze on this particular step? How do I fix this? I cannot not delete extra rows. Here is the exact piece of code where it freezes.

```
var unwanted = newAssignmentSheet.getMaxRows() - (parseInt(i) + 6);
newAssignmentSheet.deleteRows(i+7, unwanted); //FREEZES HERE
```

Point to note :

If I implement Step 6 in isolation, the Spreadsheet does not freeze.

Comment: How much work are the formulas doing? Could they be recalculating after you delete the row?

Comment: If you do all those steps manually, does it work fine?  Need to isolate whether the issue is the code, or the spreadsheet itself.  If it turns out to be a bug, you can report it.  Unfortunately, you might have a lot of work to do to try to simplify being able to recreate the problem so someone else can verify and test it.

Comment: @SpencerEaston the formulas are the basic Max, Min, Avg and Median formulas provided by the SpreadsheetApp and the range provided are cells from rows that are not deleted so I dont think they are getting recalculated.

Comment: @SandyGood if I manually perform these steps it works. The only difference being is it takes about 10 secs to complete all these step using the script but a minute-ish when I do it manually so maybe its the speed at which I perform all these tasks. I am pretty sure I will be able to replicate this issue on a new sheet. All you need to do is perform multiple modification to the spreadsheet out of which atleast one step is deleting rows. The interesting part is if I remove the "deleting rows step" and add multiple extra steps(i added 5), it does not crash.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that if you leave at least one empty row below the last contingent cell, the spreadsheet will not become unresponsive.